# My font weight does not change within a HTML elementor widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I'm using wordpress and elementor, when for example I want to edit the font weigh of my font choice (Plus-Jakarta-Sans) there is no issues within an elementor widget.

However, when I try to do the same thing for a custom HTML widget, the font does not show up and changing the weight to 900 or black does nothing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Plus Jakarta Sans;
 
  font-size:16px;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 60s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="marquee">
  <span style="font-weight:900;">KEEP SCROLLING &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING</span>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Plus Jakarta Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font cdn url you were using doesn't look like it has the 900 font-weight embedded in it. I changed the font cdn url. I added all the available font-weights of that font. And I set the font weight to be 800 as it is the highest on fonts.google.com I hope this will help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
/* This is the link that has font weight of: 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800 */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap');

.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Plus Jakarta Sans;
 
  font-size:16px;
}

.marquee{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 60s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="marquee">
  <span style="font-weight: 800;">KEEP SCROLLING &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KEEP SCROLLING</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are welcome. If it helps then you can upvote and mark it as "accepted answer" if you want :)